# Can't have the same table names in different entity framework models?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

My application uses two different SQL 2008 databases. The databases have a few tables with the same name, ie. `Users`. I would like to use EF4 for both these databases. However, when I run my application and it hits the objectcontext creation of the second database, I get the following error:

> Multiple types with the name 'User' exist
>   in the EdmItemCollection in different
>   namespaces.  Convention based mapping
>   requires unique names without regard
>   to namespace in the EdmItemCollectionto namespace in the EdmItemCollection

Does this mean I can't use two databases with (partly) the same table names in the same application? They are in different namespaces, different edmx models, different projects, etc.

P.S. One of the models is designer-generated and uses POCO classes and the other is inferred from the database and is tightly coupled to EF.

Comment: Would changing the entity name of one of them in the Designer solve this? That does seem a little bit inconvenient, though.

Comment: I'm hoping for a different solution. This is a database conversion app (from a legacy database to the new one) so there are quite a few table names the same. Besides ending up with the wrong type names, renaming them in the designer would mean some serious refactoring in the new application.

Comment: Im having the same proble with different entity name...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error means, what he says: You can't use the **default convention based mapping** in your scenario. Use **custom database mapping** instead. Scott Guthrie has a detailed blog item about [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx).

Answer (score 22):

To use the "default convention based mapping" the following 2 approaches will work:

1)
The collision is caused by the connection string using a wild card:

```
    metadata=res://*/Repositories.EntityFramework.Model.csdl|res://*/Repositories.EntityFramework.Model.ssdl|res://*/Repositories.EntityFramework.Model.msl;
```

Since * does not work your project you can define multiple connection strings to hard code the assembly containing the edmx.

2) create a helper

```
    public static EntityConnection GetEfConnectionString(this string sqlConnectionString)
    {
        var cs = string.Format(@"metadata=res://{0}/Repositories.EntityFramework.Model.csdl|res://{0}/Repositories.EntityFramework.Model.ssdl|res://{0}/Repositories.EntityFramework.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=""" + sqlConnectionString + @"""",
            Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName
        );

        return new EntityConnection(cs);
    }
```

Update 2017:

```
    public static string GetEfConnectionString(this string sqlConnectionString, Type type)
    {
        string cs =
            string.Format(
                @"metadata=res://{0}/Models.Model.csdl|res://{0}/Models.Model.ssdl|res://{0}/Models.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=""" +
                sqlConnectionString + @"""",
                type.Assembly.FullName
                );
        return cs;
    }


    // usage: don't "new" EntityConnection.  See 2012 comment.
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConnection"].ConnectionString.GetEfConnectionString();
    using(var entities = new XyzEntities(connString))
```

Comment: This helped me quite a lot. I modded my T4 templates to implement something like that so that all models can use one connection string from config but still are able to read only their metadata. Thanks.

Comment: I just got upvoted and wanted to update this... Don't new  EntityConnection else you need to manage opening/closing the object.  Your helper should instead return the connectionstring as a string and use the overload constructor on the objectcontext ef4.0 or dbcontext ef4.1.

Comment: +1 for the simpler solution which works without Code First too.

Comment: I already created multiple connection strings, but didnt eliminate wildcard... How can I eliminate the wildcard?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but can someone tell me how to use the above extension method?  Also, I'm using EF6, not 4.  For example, my dbContext generated code calls the DbContext .ctor with a "name=string", so I'd have to manually modify that with a .ctor overload taking a connection string?

Comment: Has this solution worked for anyone? And can this answer be expanded to include a implementation example?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but my solution was to delete the DLL of the MODEL\edmx from the project, because it was copied from a different project, and then rebuild it.
Solved everything!

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for that error is what happened to me: My project was copied from somewhere else and I renamed the project, so after compiling there were 2 DLL's in my bin folder. The one from the previous project and a brand new one, named according to the new project. Once I deleted the previous/old DLL the namespace ambiguity disappeared and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

For DB first approach, Luckily there are couple of workarounds which are pretty straightforward:

1. Make sure that that both contexts don't share tables with the same
   name - not the most practical approach.
2. Restructure the solution by
   isolating the database contexts within their own assemblies.

For more detail, please refer this [link](http://www.nullfactory.net/2015/06/entity-framework-multiple-context-namespace-collision/)

Explained very clearly.