# How to avoid ambiguity with multiple standalone projects using same EF6 models

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have 2 separate projects, both use Entity Framework 6 to connect to a database and do various things. When I pull these projects together in reference, I get an error:

> The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'Account'. Previously found CLR type 'DataAccess.Entities.Account', newly found CLR type 'Package.Entities.DB.Account'.

These projects are separate and need to be able to run independently of one another. I can't think of how to NOT add the same models to each project.

**EDIT:**
After some of the comments i worked to issolate all the models inot a single class library (NuGet) that is then installed on each project needed EF6 data access. I still recieve a error in this setup:

> Multiple types with the name 'Account' exist in the EdmItemCollection
>   in different namespaces.  Convention based mapping requires unique
>   names without regard to namespace in the EdmItemCollection.

**EDIT:**
Also after doing some more digging i can across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069166/cant-have-the-same-table-names-in-different-entity-framework-models) where one of the answers is suggesting that the issue is in the connections strings. Is this a possible solution to the issue?

Is there any advice on how to avoid ambiguity in scenarios like this?

Comment: Put your models into their own project and consume them in both existing projects.

Comment: Ok, so if i create a NuGet that holds all models for all databases that i use across all applications and then install this NuGet in each project that uses the models, this should avoid my issue?

Comment: Separate your entity framework in a separate project and access it in both projects.

Comment: Agreed with @DavidG 7

Comment: I do the same. I have created a different projects for entity model and used it wherever i want

Comment: This might be a red flag that you are splitting up two things that belong together!

Comment: Thanks guys. This approach is working for me. I'd give you all points if I could. Thx.

Comment: I added a edit to my question above. I completed moving all the models into a single class library and other projects are referencing it via NuGet. This still produces the following error -- Multiple types with the name 'Account' exist in the EdmItemCollection in different namespaces.  Convention based mapping requires unique names without regard to namespace in the EdmItemCollection. -- Obviously this is because i have 2 databases with similar table names. Changing the names in the DB is not a option.